# How to have gradle download a server specified version of a dependency at build time

Tags: android, gradle, build, continuous-integration

Say I create a library and I added it as a dependency to my project gradle files.
I would like to know how and if it is possible to specify the version number on a/my server and have Gradle check the version number at build time & update the library if necessary without me having the explicitly update the version number in my gradle files.

So for example:
Say I have a whole bunch of apps which use my personal library currently at version 1. When I update my library to say version 2 I'd like, when I run build tasks for all my apps, to have Gradle check on some external location (say git repo) if the library version got updated. 
If it has been updated i want gradle to automatically handle the updating of the version number and pulling in the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, just grab the version from your server and dynamically add the version into your dependency's declaration.

```
def yourVersion = 'http://your-server/version.txt'.toURL().text

dependencies {
    compile "your-company:your-lib:$yourVersion"
}
```

Comment: Best to use a variable name other than `version` as this will "hide" `project.version`